# Can you uncompress a btrfs filesystem?

Tags: arch-linux, boot, btrfs, syslinux

I found out that you can compress the whole of a Btrfs filesystem by defragmenting it with `-clzo` or `-czlib`, but is it possible to uncompress it again? I'm asking because I managed to stop my system from booting, as `/boot` wasn't in a separate partition so `ldlinux.c32` got compressed.

I fixed this by reinstalling syslinux from a chroot after disabling compression from the fstab, but I would like to know if it's possible to uncompress a filesystem completely (and automatically). I'm using Arch Linux by the way.

Before reinstalling syslinux, I also tried defragmenting the filesystem again without specifying the compression options, but this didn't work, so my guess is that defragmenting doesn't disable compression automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [compress](https://github.com/benapetr/compress) tool with the `--decompress` option. This will recursively remove the +c (compression) flag, then copy and then the delete the original files and folders. Easiest way is probably to boot using the Arch Linux install medium (CD, USB, etc.), mount the root directory you want to decompress and run the command.

An alternative solution would be to simply re-install the Syslinux (I assume that's what you're using) files using `syslinux-install_update -i` from the Arch Linux install medium. Of course, make sure you've mounted the root partition without enabling compression.